# Broswser Compatibility Problems. Looks good in Google Chrome but not in IE or Mozilla

Tags: css, internet-explorer, mozilla

I just built my first css website and it looks fabulous in Google Chrome, but after reviewing the site for browser compatibility, I see that in both IE and Mozilla, the site is a MESS. I have no idea what to do. Where do I start to fix the problems?

Answer (score 2):

There can be no specific answer to your question, there could be any reason. The IE should be culprit for the most part; in your case though that doesn't work even in Mozila. Here are some links you may find useful:

- [Make your site cross browser compatible in 5 steps](http://www.onyx-design.net/other/cross-browser-compatible-in-5-steps/)
- [The Importance of Cross Browser Compatibility: Tips and Resources](http://www.noupe.com/tools/the-importance-of-cross-browser-compatibity-tips-and-resources.html)
- [Complete Guide to Cross-Browser Compatibility Check](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/complete-guide-to-cross-browser-compatibility-check/)
- [Cross Browser Compatibility Check Tools](http://www.ivankristianto.com/web-development/designs/cross-browser-compatibility-check-tools/1202/)

You should be aware of various inconsistencies across browsers especially modern standard compliant ones with IE. There are also some possibilities to use:

- [Eric's Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
- [IE CSS Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

And finally, it is a good idea to [validate your html at W3C](http://validator.w3.org/) just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you give no code, there are 3 basic things you can do:

1. make sure you use a DOCTYPE that is HTML 4.01 or XHTML 1.0: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html
2. validate your HTML: http://validator.w3.org/
3. validate your CSS: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

having these will make sure you are using Standard Compliant Mode of rendering, and then if some particular item is not displayed right, you can post specific portion of code to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

First, review your XHTML and the CSS and be sure you are not using anything that is coupled to a browser. See how you have used the styling. I can not give any specific answer as your question is too generic. If you use all standard ways, there will be little issues.