# How can I detect if a browser is opened in compatibility mode?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ie-compatibility-mode

How can I detect whether the browser is opened in compatibility mode or not? I have to make use of different css for compatibility and non-compatibility mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213639 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328963 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825385 , Do some research first and show us your efforts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Can I detect IE9 if it's in IE7 or IE8 compatibility mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825385/javascript-can-i-detect-ie9-if-its-in-ie7-or-ie8-compatibility-mode)

Answer (score 0):

yes, usually you will have to code out different codes for the different browsers in your css. Like for example, if it works on mozilla, it may not necessarily work on internet explorer.

try looking at this : [Broswser Compatibility Problems. Looks good in Google Chrome but not in IE or Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121243/broswser-compatibility-problems-looks-good-in-google-chrome-but-not-in-ie-or-mo)